# Каким образом я могу запускать XJC из командной строки?

Tags: windows, jaxb, переменные-среды

Я пытаюсь использовать `XJC`, чтобы сгенерировать Java-классы из XSD. Меня интересует, каким образом я могу это сделать?

Пока что я сделал следующее:

- Скачал и распаковал `JAXB`
- Установил в системную переменную `JAXB_HOME` значение `C:\Program Files\Java\jaxb-ri-2.3.1` *(адрес директории, в которую распаковано содержимое архива jaxb-ri-2.3.1)*

По-видимому этого недостаточно, так как при написании в консоли команды `xjc` появляется сообщение о том, что это неизвестная команда. Хотя в тех гайдах, которые я смотрел, этого хватало.

Что ещё я могу предпринять для решения своей проблемы?

*Система Windows 8.1, для команд использовал стандартную командную строку Windows и Git Bash.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл способ установки, при котором `XJC` будет работать корректно:

- [Загружаем](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/2.3.1/) и устанавливаем `JAXB` *(в моём случае версия 2.3.1)*. Причём путь установки не должен содержать пробелов *(для меня это было решающим)*.
- Загружаем и устанавливаем `JDK` *(я загружал версию 15.0.2 с сайт Oracle, но это не принципиальный момент)*.
- Теперь необходимо исправить файл `xjc.bat`, который находится в `\jaxb-ri-2.3.1\bin`: заменяем `/lib/` на `/mod/`, `activation.jar` на `activation-api.jar` и `relaxngDatatype.jar` на `relaxng-datatype.jar`. [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53710110/14614707).
- Устанавливаем в переменную среды `JAVA_HOME` путь к папке, в которой находятся файлы `JDK`.
- Устанавливаем в переменную среды `JAXB_HOME` путь к папке, в которой находятся файлы `JAXB`.
- Добавляем в переменную среды `PATH` пути `%JAXB_HOME%\bin` и `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

После этого можно запустить `XJC` из консоли при помощи команды `xjc.bat`.